# How do I request Facebook login/authorization upon application (Page Tab) installation?

Tags: facebook, authorization, oauth-2.0, facebook-page

I have an app that's installed as a Tab in a Facebook Page. Installation is straight forward, but unfortunately does not prompt the installer (i.e. the page admin) for authorization (ex. for "email, publish_stream" scopes) unless the user then "Logs In" to the app. My goal is that the person installing the app will be immediately prompted to authorize certain permissions so that the app can post to their wall, etc.

Is there a way to request permissions as part of the installation process? Ideally, a user would install the app in a Tab and, as part of the installation process, be prompted for permissions. Calling FB.login does not appear to work since pop-ups are blocked.

I'm using Facebook's OAuth2 and Javascript APIs. The app is backed by a (Rails) server, so I could switch to using server-based authentication, though I'd prefer not to.

I've looked through a variety of similar posts, but all of them are using legacy code (which doesn't work with Facebook's OAuth2 support) or require the user to click the Log In button:

- [How to show the Extended Permission Dialog in FB using new Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211033/how-to-show-the-extended-permission-dialog-in-fb-using-new-graph-api)
- [How do I get my Facebook application to automatically ask for the required permissions post installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955615/how-do-i-get-my-facebook-application-to-automatically-ask-for-required-permissio)
- [Facebook iframe application after authorization redirect to facebook page tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143045/facebook-iframe-application-after-authorization-redirect-to-facebook-page-tab)
- [How to Detect a user declining a permissions request dialog that redirects to a Facebook TAB application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984934/how-to-detect-a-user-declining-a-permissions-request-dialog-that-redirects-to-a)

Any suggestions?

Comment: FB.ui is only useful if the user is already logged in. What I want is to prompt them to login automatically upon installation.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this question? I'm interested in this.